# How to query using MySQL in an EJS File

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

I am trying to run a query in a view (.ejs file). However, since the keyword require is not defined in a .ejs file, I need to export it from my main file, server.js.

The whole code for my server.js file is below and this is the specific snippet with which I need help.

**app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);**

**exports.profile = function(req, res) {**

**res.render('profile', { mysql: mysql });
}**

I need to be able to use the mysql.createConnection in my profile.ejs file.

Any help would be great.

```html
// server.js

// set up ======================================================================
// get all the tools we need
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash    = require('connect-flash');

var morgan       = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
var session      = require('express-session');

var configDB = require('./config/database.js');
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var config = {
userName: 'DESKTOP-S6CM9A9\\Yash',
password: '',
server: 'DESKTOP-S6CM9A9\\SQLEXPRESS',
};
var Request = require('tedious').Request;
var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;

  var mysql = require('mysql');
  var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "yashm"
  });

 con.connect(function(err) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log("Connected!");
var sql="Select * from test.productlist";
con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(result);
});
});

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);


exports.profile = function(req, res) {
    res.render('profile', { mysql: mysql });
}



//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------




// configuration ===============================================================
mongoose.connect(configDB.url); // connect to our database

require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration

// set up our express application
app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(bodyParser()); // get information from html forms

app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // set up ejs for templating

// required for passport
app.use(session({ secret: 'test run' })); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session

// routes ======================================================================
require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport); // load our routes and pass in our app and fully configured passport

// launch ======================================================================
app.listen(port);
console.log('The magic happens on port ' + port);
```

Comment: You don't need mysql in your view. Your logic should be in your controller (server.js) en from there just pass some data to your view.

Comment: I tried that too but I wasn't able to render the result set to the view page.

Comment: I'll try it again though then. Also, what would I do for the reverse, when I want a button click to insert data into my database? Pass the data to my controller and then run it in controller?

Comment: Maybe you should reformat? Does the query works? And for posting back data, pass the data to the controller using a form/ajax/... and indeed run your query in the controller

Comment: Yes, the query is running in the cmd and displaying the results.

Answer (score 1):

Like already said in the comment, you have to do your query logic in your server.js and then pass the data to your view (or maybe even pre-process it!)

```
exports.profile = function(req, res) {
    con.query('SELECT 1', function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      // connected!
      res.render('profile', { data: results });
    });
}
```

In your ejs you can loop trough the data, and acces the fields as data[i]['fieldname']

```
<ul>
<% for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {%>
   <li><%= data[i]['id'] %></li>
<% } %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Okay, I tried doing this earlier but I am not understanding how to access this data in my view after passing the result set. I basically want to display it as a table which means I need to access individual rows and add it in <td>.

Sorry for the simple questions, I just started Node.js 2 days ago.

Comment: II modified my answer to include a simple loop. You can modify this code so it looks like table rows instead of li elements.

Comment: Thanks but it isn't working. I know how to write the loop but even a single access isn't working.

For instance <td><%= data[1]['Price'] %></td> isn't working. I think the data is not being rendered only.

Is there something else that I need to include in the server file for the render to work?

Comment: This is the error being shown on the profile page while running:



ReferenceError: E:\LoginForm\views\profile.ejs:184 182| 183| <ul> >> 184| <% for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {%> 185| <li><%= data[i]['id'] %></li> 186| <% } %> 187| </ul> data is not defined at eval (eval at <anonymous> (E:\LoginForm\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:237:14))

Comment: And you are sure you pass the results (which you can console.log and are not null?) to the controller like in the answer? (res.render('profile', { data: results });) Also, make sure you only call res.render once. The query is aync, so you should only call res.render in the callback

Comment: Yep,if I console.log,I am able to view the result set in cmd.

And yes, res.render is only called once. Is there anything extra that I need to add to the server file or the route file?

The profile page immediately stops working as soon as I add <%= data[1]['Price'] %> to my code.

I've no clue.

Comment: Maybe app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); instead of app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile); ?